# Can't share application window in Chrome

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, nvidia-geforce

I think this is a Ubuntu issue, because on the same laptop I don't have this problem in Windows.

When trying to share an Application window in Chrome, no windows are available.

[image: No options for Application Window]

Output of Display drivers:

```
SCSI                        
  *-display        
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:142 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:138 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Using Ubuntu 19.10 and Chrome browser. Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Sharing the entire screen works just fine.

Comment: Wayland session or X session?

Comment: not wayland, just a normal session.